# Is it possible to cast from one enum to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, enums, casting

I need to populate a new table in a second schema from an existing one, but having problems casting the "schema1.a.disclosure_level" column enum to the "schema2.b.disclosure_level" enum. A cast via ::text or :: varchar did not help. Casting to ::schema1.a.disclosure_level raises a cross-database reference error.

```
INSERT INTO schema1.a (id, disclosure_level)
SELECT schema2.b.id, schema2.b.disclosure_level
FROM schema2.b;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "*A cast via ::text or :: varchar did not help.*" - it should. Can you show us what exactly you tried?

Comment: Taking Adrian's example from below: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a13c8681aed4e0829ac557f51a9de343

Comment: ```
INSERT INTO schema1.a (id, disclosure_level)
SELECT schema2.b.id, schema2.b.disclosure_level::text::schema1.a.disclosure_level
FROM schema2.b;
```
But I get this error:
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented

Comment: That has nothing to do with enums or text conversion, it's just that postgres doesn't allow  schema-qualified column references (just `b` and `a` for referencing the `FROM`-clause tables, or their aliases, would be enough), and that `schema1.a.disclosure_level` is not a type - you need to use the type name of the enum for casting, not a column that has this type.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi
That worked. I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Bergi showed me the solution.

```
INSERT INTO schema1.a (id, disclosure_level)
SELECT schema2.b.id, schema2.b.disclosure_level::text:schema1.disclosure_level_enum
FROM schema2.b;
```

where my fault was to use the column name instead of the enum type definition in the cast: `schema1.disclosure_level_enum` (type) instead of `schema1.a.disclosure_level` (column)!

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `schema1.disclosure_level_enum` (without the `a`)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I removed the table name "a" as it was wrong in the cast.

Comment: I believe you need another colon in your statement to be syntactically correct.

`schema2.b.disclosure_level::text::schema1.disclosure_level_enum`

Answer (score 2):

It can be possible if you cast to VARCHAR as first and second to another enum

```sql
 "valueType" = NEW."valueType"::VARCHAR::"enum_second"
```

Comment: seconded, they even advise to do this here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30186/90467

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html

> 8.7.3. Type Safety

> Each enumerated data type is separate and cannot be compared with other enumerated types.

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE animal AS ENUM ('dog', 'cat', 'rabbit');
CREATE TYPE animal_2 AS ENUM ('dog', 'cat', 'rabbit');

create table enum_test(id integer, a animal, a2 animal_2);
insert into enum_test values (1, 'dog', 'cat');

select a::animal from enum_test ;
  a  
-----
 dog

 
select a::animal_2 from enum_test ;
ERROR:  cannot cast type animal to animal_2
LINE 1: select a::animal_2 from enum_test ;
```

So the answer is no you can't cast one enum to another.